# Print Max Subarray Values From An Array After Running Divide And Conquer Algorithm

Tags: c, arrays, algorithm, sub-array

I have implemented a solution to find the maximum subarray from an array of values. I can print out the full array prior to running my divide and conquer algorithm, but I cannot seem to figure out how to print the subarray after the algorithm is run.

```
int newArray[] = {31, -41, 59, 26, -53, 58, 97, -93, -23, 84};

int arraySize = (sizeof(newArray)/sizeof(int));

printArray(newArray, 0, arraySize - 1);

int total = maxSubDiv(newArray, 0, arraySize - 1);
```

This is a snippet of my main function. I am using a printArray function to print the full array prior to finding the maximum subarray. The maxSubDiv function is as follows:

```
int maxSubDiv(int * Array1, int left, int right)
{
    if(left == right)
    {
        return Array1[1];
    }

    int middle = (left + right)/2;

    return findMax(maxSubDiv(Array1, left, middle), maxSubDiv(Array1, middle + 1, right), leftRightCross(Array1, left, middle, right));

}

int leftRightCross(int * Array1, int left, int middle, int right)
{
    int sum = 0;

    int leftSum = INT_MIN;

    for(int i = middle; i >= left; i--)
    {
        sum = sum + Array1[i];
        if(sum > leftSum)
        {
            leftSum = sum;
        }
    }

    sum = 0;
    int rightSum = INT_MIN;

    for(int i = middle + 1; i <= right; i++)
    {
        sum = sum + Array1[i];
        if(sum > rightSum)
        {
            rightSum = sum;
        }
    }

    sum = leftSum + rightSum;

    return sum;
}
```

The algorithm seems to test well, but I am just having trouble printing out the subarray that contains the integers of the max subarray. Any help is much appreciated!

```
struct tuple{

    int begin;
    int end;
    int length;

};

int findMax(int left, int right, int cross)
{

    int max;
    if(left > right && left > cross)
    {
        max = left;
    }

    else if(right > left && right > cross)
    {
        max = right;
    }

    else
    {
        max = cross;
    }

    return(left, right, cross);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In `maxSubDiv()` when you compare the max of three subarrays, return tuple (begin, end, length) of the max subarray instead of just the length. `"begin"`, `"end"` specifies the range of the max subarray, which you can leverage later for print. You should also return (begin, end, length) from `leftRightCross()`.

E.g.,

```
// pesudocode
if max is left:
   return (left_begin, left_end, left_length)
if max is right:
   return (right_begin, right_end, right_length)
if max is middle:
   return (middle_begin, middle_end, middle_length)
```

The tuple can be implemented in `struct` in C.

Comment: I understand the concept, I am just having trouble figuring out how to implement it. I am posting some more coded above.